# How do I "Link" a channel like a mention in my Discord Bot message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'd like our Discord Bot to mention a specific channel, and let it be clickable. I understand mentioning a user you use the user ID. I do have the channel Id, just unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to do the following:

```
message.channel.send('Please take a look at this Discord Server channel <#CHANNELID>')
```

or if you get the channel id from the bot

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'Name of the channel');
message.channel.send(`Please take a look at this Discord Server channel <#${channel.id}>`)
```

Then the channel is clickable like in this screenshot:

[image: Overview how a clickable channel looks like]

Answer (score 6):

It is simple :^)

```
<#channel.id>
```

Answer (score 1):

Channels on Discord have this special kinda syntax here:

```
<#channel id>
```

As commented by Elitezen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354321/how-to-get-a-discord-bot-send-a-channel-fx-general), running [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/tostring) on a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) can do that mention for you. Then, just send that string yourself. It's much simpler than manually doing it.

Like this if you're answering a message:

```js
message.channel.send(message.channel.toString());
```

Also, like answered by others in this question, you can do that yourself if you feel like it.

If you have a Channel object already, you can do something like this (imagine your channel is named `myChannel` - it doesn't have to be named that, though):

```js
message.channel.send(`<#${message.channel.id}>`);
```